# Is 'quick.db" supported on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, quick.db

I receive this error whenever I run an application which requires the quick.db
Here's the error:
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing preventing you from building the `quick.db` dependency into your application but it will not work as expected. It uses `sqlite` under the hood which will attempt to store your data in the file system. On Heroku, that file system is [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) and your data will be wiped at least once per day.

Comment: I saw this a long time after you have posted it, but is there a workaround to this while still using quick.db?